# Loophole of an if inside a while

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

I've made this program that requires the user to input 6 different numbers and i made it so if it's not happy with the numbers he can change them. The thing is that i put this condition so it would reedit the numbers but it seems to be loopholeing in the var of the input "cambio" that checks if it's happy with the numbers.

```
import random

def ingreso_numeros():
    
    while len(nums_usuario) < 6:

        num = int(input("Ingrese un número del 0 al 15: "))
        
        if num in range(0,15) and num not in nums_usuario:
            nums_usuario.append(num)
            
        elif num not in range(0,15) and num not in nums_usuario:
            print("El número ingresado no está entre 0 y 15")
                              
        elif num in range(0,15) and num in nums_usuario:
            print("El número ya fue ingresado")

        else:
            ("Machine Broke, contact supervisor")

    print("Sus números ingresados son:",nums_usuario)

def quini_numeros():

    while len(nums_quini) < 6:
        x = randint(0,15)
        
        if x not in nums_quini:
            nums_quini.append(x)
            conteo+=1

        else:
            pass
        
    #testeo#
    print(nums_quini)
    #testeo#
    
## ------------ main -----------------------------------------
            
nums_quini = []
nums_usuario = []
opcion = True

ingreso_numeros()


while opcion == True:

    cambio = input("¿Desea cambiar sus números? Sí(S)/No(N): ").upper
    
    if cambio == "S":
        nums_usuario.clear()
        ingreso_numeros()

    elif cambio == "N":
        opcion = False
        quini_numeros()
```

Comment: can you provide a running example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: yeah but i made the if statement inside the while loop so if the user inputs "S" it should clear the list and activate the function to rewrite it and if the user writes "N", break the loop by changing the status of cambio to False

Comment: done, i thought that i already clicked it (btw: beautiful place Cuenca, i was there for 2 months during march)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not calling the method `upper`, then the value of `cambio` is `<function str.upper>`, and none of the conditions is executed which keeps you in an infinite loop.

```py
cambio = input("¿Desea cambiar sus números? Sí(S)/No(N): ").upper() # use ()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think looking at your code, I imagine you are going the route of checking if random ints are the same as what the user has entered.

I tried your code in python3 and found a couple of issues which I fixed. Hope this helps you progress.

```
import random
from random import randint

def ingreso_numeros():
    while len(nums_usuario) < 6:
        num = int(input("Ingrese un numero del 0 al 15: "))
        if num in range(0,15) and num not in nums_usuario:
            nums_usuario.append(num)
        elif num not in range(0,15) and num not in nums_usuario:
            print("El numero ingresado no esta entre 0 y 15")
        elif num in range(0,15) and num in nums_usuario:
            print("El numero ya fue ingresado")

        else:
            ("Machine Broke, contact supervisor")

    print("Sus numeros ingresados son:",nums_usuario)

def quini_numeros():

    # you should declare before using a var
    conteo = 0
    while len(nums_quini) < 6:
        x = randint(0,15)
        if x not in nums_quini:
            nums_quini.append(x)
            conteo+=1

        else:
            pass
    #testeo#
    print(nums_quini)
    #testeo#
## ------------ main -----------------------------------------
nums_quini = []
nums_usuario = []
opcion = True

ingreso_numeros()


while opcion == True:

    cambio = input("enter your numbers? Yes(S)/No(N): ").upper()
    print (cambio)
    if cambio == "S":
        print(nums_usuario)
        nums_usuario.clear()
        ingreso_numeros()

    elif cambio == "N":
        opcion = False
        quini_numeros()
```

Comment: yeah, after the (not) loophole problem i saw them and solved everything, thanks a lot anyway